# argument for constructor of elements in std::array

Tags: templates, c++11

The following prints "1\n 1\n 1" as expected. Can I construct "ar" in a way that it will print "2\n 2\n 2" without giving it an explicit initializer list (... ar = {A(2), A(2), A(2)})?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class A {

public:
    A(int i=1) : m_i(i) {};
    int m_i;
};

int main() {

    std::array<A, 3> ar;

    for(auto& v : ar) {
        std::cout << v.m_i << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really; `array` doesn't have any interesting constructors like `vector`'s `vector(size_type, T = T())`.

The closest you can get is to use `fill`, possibly with an initializing lambda:

```
std::array<A, 3> ar = []{ std::array<A, 3> ar; ar.fill(2); return ar; }();
```